# Converting string[] to double[]

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a text file that is being read in and then stored in a `string[]` which I then then convert into an `int[]`, my bubblesort then should sort it but it doesn't because the values from the text files are decimals. So my question is how do I convert either the `string[]` or `int[]` to something that can accept decimal values, such as a `double[]` if there is such a thing. Thanks.

Code:

```
string[] sh1OpenData = File.ReadAllLines("SH1_Open.txt");
```

...

```
else if(input2.ToLower() == "open") //----
{
    int[] intSh1OpenData = new int[sh1OpenData.Length];

    for (int x = 0; x < sh1OpenData.Length; x++)
    {
        intSh1OpenData[x] = Convert.ToInt32(sh1OpenData[x]);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\n");
    Console.WriteLine("Unsorted");

    for (int i = 0; i < intSh1OpenData.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(intSh1OpenData[i] + " ");
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
    }

    int temp = 0; 

    for (int write = 0; write < intSh1OpenData.Length; write++) 
    {
        for (int sort = 0; sort < intSh1OpenData.Length - 1; sort++) 
        {
            if (intSh1OpenData[sort] > intSh1OpenData[sort + 1]) 
            {
                temp = intSh1OpenData[sort + 1];
                intSh1OpenData[sort + 1] = intSh1OpenData[sort];
                intSh1OpenData[sort] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
        Console.WriteLine("\n\n\nSORTED");

    for (int i = 0; i < intSh1OpenData.Length; i++)
        Console.Write(intSh1OpenData[i] + "\n");
}
```

Comment: are you using bubblesort for a particular reason? Or are you just trying to sort the array and all you know is bubblesort?

Comment: Convert.ToDouble() ?

Comment: `bubblesort`ing ? How about a nice [Bogo Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogosort) instead?

Comment: Yeah, that's basically the gist of it.

Comment: @Guillaume Yeah that works fine but when I compile and run the code and then try and read in the file it doesnt work because the text file contains decimals and obviously Int's cant be decimal.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using int to do comparisons on string. Use String.Compare(return 0 if equal, -1 if less than, or 1 if greater than) or List.Sort() to sort string array

Comment: Well my Text File contains only decimal values, so they should be read as double or floats, surely? Plus, I am testing my Algorithm writing skills.

Comment: Have you tried Double.Parse() or Float.Parse() to convert string to its representing type?

Comment: how exactly do I use that? I'm new to programming, sorry.

Comment: string[] sh1OpenData = File.ReadAllLines("SH1_Open.txt"); gives you the lines of the text file. I wont give the direct answer in code away since youre learning, but find a way (possibly a loop?) to go through every line and parse its content into a float or double (using Type.Parse(line)) . And store in a List of some sort to have a nice array of converted input.

Answer (score 0):

The only changes that you will need to make are listed below:

```
double[] intSh1OpenData = new double[sh1OpenData.Length]; // double[] instead of int[]

for (int x = 0; x < sh1OpenData.Length; x++)
{
    intSh1OpenData[x] = Convert.ToDouble(sh1OpenData[x]); // Convert to Double
}
```

also change the declaration of your `temp` variable to `double temp;`

Something that you could read through since you mentioned that you are new to programming:
[C# Sort Arrays and Lists Examples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sort)
[MSDN: List.Sort Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple with LINQ

```
var asDouble = sh1OpenData.Select(x => Double.Parse(x)).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
```

This will give you a sorted (ascending order) array of `Double`.

Note: this assumes that all of `sh1OpenData` can be parsed as a `Double`, and will throw an exception if not.

Comment: Cool. Just to add to this, maybe something can be done with the PredicateBuilder to check if it can be parsed?